# What is my "App ID"? Where is it?

Tags: facebook

I signed up for Facebook APPS, now where is my app ID? Is it a number? Where do I find it? It's required for facebook moderation, and it asks for this app id, but it is nowhere to be found. Nowhere.

Comment: Please remember to tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a website.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Facebook usage. You might find help on webapps.stackexchange.com, but consult their FAQ first.

Answer (score 2):

Go to developers.facebook.com. List of apps should be on the left. The AppID/API Key should be right under the "Settings" header.